# Creating best hand on activities on how to teach equal sharing with fractions in grade 3

Tags: primary-education

(a) How to enhance learners interest in learning equal sharing with fractions in grade 3?
(b) Which effective activities will be used to help learners in learning fractions?
(c) What can be created to teach equal sharing to grade 3?

Comment: Welcome to ME.SE. How old are children in grade three (so what kind of education system is this about); giving a country would help. You could also write a little about what you already know.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the best manipulative for sharing is food, especially if the children are going to get to eat it afterwards.

1. I have used saltines for fourths. One saltine is a whole and the four sections are fourths.
2. I have used juice boxes.  A package of 8 juice boxes is one whole and each juice box is one eighth.
3. Cereal is very good to use because you can make a group of any number of pieces be the whole and so you have control over the size of the group and the fraction. Fruit loops have the added benefit of being different colors.

If you are going to use food, remember to take into account any allergies, parent preferences (some schools limit sugar at the parent's request), and hygiene.  Are the children going to eat what they handle?  In that case they need to have clean hands when they start and instructions not to touch their faces or shoes while they are handling the food.

If you want to avoid food, you can use sheets of small stickers and cut them into groups of whatever size you'd like.

As for activities.  Divide children into pairs, threes, or different sized groups. Decide what is the whole. Give the children an amount which is a multiple of the group size.

Here is one activity:  Have the whole be 24 pieces of cereal.  Divide children into groups of 2, 3, 4, and 6. Demonstrate with a group of 3.  Figure out what fraction of the group each child is - for example 3 children - each child is 1/3.  Then give them 1 whole (24 pieces of cereal) and tell them to share equally.  Have them write 1/3 of 24 is 8 (since they will each get 8).  Have each group share their cereal and write a similar sentence.  When they have the write sentence - add cereal so that each child has 10.  Emphasize that the bigger denominators have less of a share because there are more children to share with, so 1/2 is greater than 1/3.

Here is another activity.  Divide children into pairs.  Have them divide different amounts of cereal.  The children will see halves of different numbers.

Hope this helps.